# Null pointer dereference not causing segfault in VS2010 windows app

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, null

I have a console app I'm working on that is having behavior I've never seen before:   NULL pointer dereferences aren't causing SEGFAULT or any sort of exception.   There's even nothing being printed in the output window of the debugger, suggesting that there's no exception at all being generated.

I have code that does the following:

```
uint32_t *pointer = NULL;
*pointer = 5;
```

pointer is definitely all zeros (I've printed it out, inspected it in the debugger, compared it to zero, etc).

This causes absolutely nothing untoward to happen and it merrily steps over it.   I went to the exception dialog and turned on 'break on all thrown exceptions', and still nothing.  I know null pointer references are undefined, but my experience to this date is that Visual Studio projects catch these, particularly in the debugger.

I highly suspect I've got some compiler setting fiddled with, but I have no clue what setting that might be.  It should be a bog standard native console app, but the project settings have been under the control of an intern...

This is VS2010 ultimate, windows7-64bit, console app.  I think it's win32, but it might be 64bit.

Anyways, anybody have any clues to check when I get to the office tomorrow?

Comment: Maybe it's optimizing out the assignment?

Comment: I don't think so.   In debug mode, optimizations are turned off.   But...This came to the forefront when I had one of our summer interns add some functionality to one of our build flow tools

Comment: I don't think so.   

This came to light when I had a summer intern add some functionality to a build tool and he wasn't very rigorous.   I noticed by leaving off a command line argument it would end up passing a NULL around the program that is definitely being used as a data struct that I'm certain is being accessed.

I expected leaving the argument out would cause it to hit the exception and break in the debugger (and therefor he could use that to find all the unprotected accesses) but it just "worked" but produced incorrect results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel mildly stupid, yet relieved I'm not crazy.

Apparently, the Windows7 run time environment only cordons off the first 64KB of the virtual memory space and the elements of my structure I was pointing to were past 64K, so

```
  struct MyStruct
    {
        unsigned char Filler[64*1024];
        unsigned int  MyMemberPast64KB;
    };

   struct MyStruct *pStruct=NULL;
   pStruct->MyMemberPast64KB = 2;
```

doesn't cause the exception.   It was an inconvenient coincidence that the only elements of my class that were being used when the command line argument wasn't passed were state variables that happened to be declared after some very large working buffers.

Comment: Moral: when posting a minimal example, _compile it_ and check to make sure it actually reproduces the problem you are asking for help with.